# jquery switch action on a button after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I'm trying to toggle between an two actions on a button.

Currently clicking 'Top / Reveal' works when the yellow block scrolls up. Clicking the button again should then move the yellow block down to reveal the height of the green block.

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/XFcJe/2/)

**HTML**

```
    <div class="block">
     <h2>This is green block is fixed</h2>

</div>
<div class="content" id="here">
    <div class="headerbar"> <a href="#here">Top / Reveal</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("a href='#here'").click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, "slow");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Your example does not work.  You are missing an element with the class `slidingDiv` (in your jsfiddle).

Comment: Sorry. Updated the example now: http://jsfiddle.net/XFcJe/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just toggle your `scrollTop` param like so:

```
scrollTop: $("body").scrollTop() == 0 ? 300 : 0
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XFcJe/5/